# Can you make goulash using winter squash instead of cabbage?

Tags: meat

I am really craving goulash today, but I don't have any cabbage. However I have a winter squash, its orange inside, quite like a pumpkin, but not quite a pumpkin, as the skin is green-orange. No, its not an unripe pumpkin, its just squash like this.

I will also use ghee, goat meat and spring onion, because I don't have normal onions. And a tiny cast iron pot, and only making a small portion, for 1 person, 1 meal.

Will that work to make goulash?

Comment: I am slightly confused: I wouldn’t expect any vetegetables (apart from onions and maybe mushrooms) in a goulash, and certainly not cabbage. Could you please add your recipe or at least the regional/cuisine where your dish comes from?

Comment: I don't have any specific recipe, it just in my mind that goulash, eaten in Eastern Europe, always had cabbage. Haven't eaten it for many years so maybe I don't remember very well.

Comment: eastern european here :) Gulasch in Austria, pörkölt in Hungary do not contain cabbage/squash etc. only onions, sometimes pepper and tomato. some versions may contain potatoes or mushrooms. Goulash/pörkölt: https://www.spendwithpennies.com/hungarian-goulash/, https://www.daringgourmet.com/hungarian-beef-and-onion-stew-marhaporkolt/ Maybe you thought about this one (with the cabbage): https://cookpad.com/uk/recipes/6995401-hungarian-cabbage-stew-in-szekely-in-hungarian-szekelykaposzta

Comment: @G.B. Both my Hungarian team mates and my Hungarian great-gran would very much agree. Yannn, are you thinking about [Borscht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borscht), which is often made with cabbage and beets?

Comment: @G.B. Yes, certainly what is called there "Hungarian Cabbage Stew" Székelykáposzta was what I thought was called goulash. Only the one I ate was less liquid, more meat, about half meat half cabbage. No beets certainly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so as we established in the comments, you don’t need cabbage for goulash. The easiest solution would be to leave it out.

However, goulash is just one version of meat stew. And the principle of stew (with or without meat) is “throw what you have in a pot” - way older than any documented recipe. The flavor profile will also be heavily influenced by the spices used and different cooking cultures have different traditions. If you have goat meat, squash and spring onions and would like to serve them together, go for it. You can call it “stew” or “goulash” just as you see fit. (Especially as you are not going to serve it to guests that may have certain expectations when hearing “goulash”.)

As far as cooking method goes, remember that squash will soften way quicker than cabbage and meat, so either expect it to fully disintegrate (like onions in goulash) or add the pieces later.

Comment: Thanks, so I threw what I had in a pot: about 250g goat meat and the same amount of winter squash, a little sprint onion, some dried thyme and basil, added a few spoons of ghee, about half an hour in a tiny 500 mL cast iron pot on the lowest setting of an electric hob, about 100 W power, and it worked, even the squash was still recognizable. Not a traditional goulash probably, but I liked it, would do again!